# Serialize directory tree to send over TCP

Tags: c, recursion, tcp, tree

I am sending a dirtree over TCP to a client application. Dir node is a structure that looks like this:

```
struct node {
      char *name;
      int count_subnodes;
      struct node **subnodes;
 };
```

To serialize:

```
void serialize(void *buffer, struct node *n, int *c){
    int i;
    if(!n)
        return;
    memcpy(buffer+(*c), n, sizeof(*n));
    *c+=sizeof(n);
    for(i = 0; i < n->count_subnodes; i++){
        serialize(buffer, n->subnode[i], c);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It segfaults when I call serialize recursively for subnodes. Also, would I need any sort of marker for delimitation so that I can reconstruct tree on client side?

Edit: c is to keep count of current position in buffer.

EDIT 2: Typo. It was sizeof(*n) not c. Sorry

Comment: Maybe your buffer is too small?  Hard to tell w/o knowing anything about the  actual tree or the buffer.

Comment: I have given a large memory for testing. I did `buffer = calloc(600,1)` which for my example is sufficiently large. Do you see any issue with the implementation?

Answer (score 1):

1. How do you know your buffer is big enough?
2. `sizeof(n)` will give the the size of the pointer, not the struct; use `sizeof(*n)`
3. Check that `n->subnode[i]` is not `NULL`

Comment: You're right about 2. But I changed it to sizeof(*n) and I am still getting seg fault. For 1: Size is lage enough, I am sure. With gdb, I see it segfaults the moment I call serialize with subnode

Answer (score -1):

You are copying the struct n, and giving it the sizeof `c`, which is an `int*`. I think your problem is with this line:

```
memcpy(buffer+(*c), n, sizeof(c));
```

Also, you really don't want to serialize the struct itself. If you do, then you're sending over a pointer to the name, when you really want to send the name instead.

I think you need to serialize the `name` and also the sub-node count. Maybe something like:

```
int name_length = strlen(n->name + 1); /* +1 for null terminator. */
memcpy(buffer+(*c), n->name, name_length);
*c += name_length;
memcpy(buffer+(*c), &n->count_subnodes, sizeof(n->count_subnodes));
*c += sizeof(n->count_subnodes);
```

Do keep in mind that when serializing binary data for different systems, you may run into [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues.

Make sure you're allocating `buffer` to be large enough. Overrunning `buffer` could certainly segfault. It could also be in how you are initially calling `serialize`. You also need to be sure that your `node` tree is valid with no dangling pointers. And you must be passing a valid `int*` in for `c`.

You might want to post a minimal example of the calling code.

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. Changed it.

Comment: Why would this cause a segfault, and not just a garbage serialization?

Comment: Answers don't typically have questions within them.

Comment: I am callocing it like I mentioned in comment, to a sufficiently large memory. i will try your answer.

Comment: @Scott Apparently I'm not allowed to comment, should I just refrain from trying to help then?

Comment: I think you're being very helpful. Thanks a lot! I am giving you answer a try.

Comment: @rileyk: You could re-phrase your answer in the form of an answer.

Comment: @rileyk I guess I am not de-referencing the double pointer properly. Do you think that part is correct?

Comment: @Neo Do you mean `n->subnode[i]`. That is correct, but would segfault if your tree is not built properly to begin with. Are you allocating enough memory for subnode when you build your tree? And do you set each subnode properly?

Comment: I do not do it myself. I am using a dynamic lib(.so) that does it and it is tested to be working fine. I am wondering why the subnode would be empty, because there are subnodes. Anyway, I will check again.